# Native Deno (v1.32.3) ffi dlopen() method - error 'module not found'

Tags: javascript, ffi, chromium-embedded, deno

I want to access CEF (Chromium Extended Frame) through Deno native ffi. I saw 3rd party Deno libraries but I want to use as much Deno native code as possible. One of the reasons for that is that I noticed that the Deno team added test-code to also use ffi from workers.

I know that Deno native ffi is still marked unstable.

**Question Context:**

> Operating System:         windows
>
> Application Path:         D:\Projects\Deno\TestCEF
>
> Location deno.exe:        D:\Projects\Deno
>
> Deno Core:                1.32.3
>
> Deno Standard Library:    0.182.0
>
> TypeScript:               5.0.3
>
> V8 Engine:                11.2.214.9
>
> Location of CEF Library:  D:\Projects\Deno\CEF\libcef.dll
>
> CEF location as file URL: file:///D:/Projects/Deno/CEF/libcef.dll
>
> CEF version:              Latest version for windows
>
> Run in Windows CLI from:   D:\Projects\Deno\TestCEF>
>
> Command:                   deno  run  --allow-all --unstable
> --allow-ffi .\main.ts
>
> Error message:             Could not open library: The specified
> module could not be found.
>
> Method:                    Deno.dlopen()
>
> Needed Imports:            none
>
> Code:                      Ignore the 'fnname' line below, it is a
> placeholder that I will change.
> I need to pass the above error message first.

```
const ceflib = Deno.dlopen(
    "file:///D:/Projects/Deno/CEF/libcef.dll",
    {
      "fnname": { parameters: ["p1dt", "p2dt"], result: "rvdt" },
    } as const
  );
```

Verifications              - I check with Win Explorer that the file exist at the location
- I check with Win Explorer that the file is accessible.
- I wrote  a small test program to check if Deno could see the file

```
export async function ListDirectoryContent(aPath : string): Promise<void> 
{
  console.log("Files Found in path " + aPath+" :");
  for await (const dirEntry of Deno.readDir(aPath)) 
  {
    console.log("\t"+dirEntry.name);
  }
}
```

When provided with the CEF path "D:\Projects\Deno\CEF" as the input for aPath then the log output is libcef.dll, which shows Deno accessed the directory.
I run this code BEFORE I call dlopen() as a visible check to be sure that the CEF module is there.

dlopen() seems located in the Deno source at deno-1.32.3\ext\ffi\00_ffi.js

```
function dlopen(path, symbols) {
  return new DynamicLibrary(pathFromURL(path), symbols);
}
```

The error occurs in the first line of the Constructor of the DynamicLibrary class which is defined in the same 00_ffi.js file..

```
class DynamicLibrary {
  #rid;
  symbols = {};

  constructor(path, symbols) {
    ({ 0: this.#rid, 1: this.symbols } = ops.op_ffi_load({ path, symbols }));

  ...
```

More precisely the error is inside the ops.op_ffi_load({ path, symbols }) which is confirmed by the line/column number in the Deno error message trace.

From there I can't find the op_ffi_load() which would have been my next step to get to the cause of the error. The error message itself does not provide any further depth.

> error: Uncaught Error: Could not open library: The specified module
> could not be found.
>
> ```
>  const ceflib = Deno.dlopen(
>
>                      ^
>
>     at new DynamicLibrary (ext:deno_ffi/00_ffi.js:**416:46**)
>
>     at Object.dlopen (ext:deno_ffi/00_ffi.js:546:10)
>
>     at ProjectMain (file:///D:/Projects/Deno/TestCEF/TestCEF.ts:36:22)
> ```

QUESTION

Is there anyone that can see anything wrong with the above code/approach that might explain the error OR is there possibly already an open source ffi CEF integration using Deno's NATIVE ffi from which I can learn.

ADDED on request, minimal code to reproduce the error.
The code below in main.ts
Started with: deno  run  --allow-all --unstable --allow-ffi .\main.ts

```
ProjectMain();

async function ProjectMain(): Promise<void> 
{
  
  // Open CEF Library
  // -> NOTE: "fnname" is placeholders to be replace if passed the open error
  // -> error: Uncaught Error: Could not open library: The specified module could not be found
  // -> libcef.dll is present at that location (not read-only, I checked)
  const ceflib = Deno.dlopen(
    new URL("file:///D:/Projects/Deno/CEF/libcef.dll"),
    {
      "fnname": { parameters: ["isize", "isize"], result: "isize" },
    } as const
  ); 

  return;
}
```

The libcef.dll file comes from this link https://cef-builds.spotifycdn.com/index.html, Standard Distribution for windows and resides in the /Release directory. I copied the .dll to the directory shown in the code above and made sure it was not read-only or so.

Comment: The first argument to [`Deno.dlopen`](https://deno.land/api@v1.32.3?unstable=&s=Deno.dlopen) must be of type `string | URL`. If a `string` is provided, it must be a valid filesystem path. If a `file:` URL is provided, it must actually be an instance of the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class. So, in your code example, providing the string `"file:///D:/Projects/Deno/CEF/libcef.dll"` is not a valid argument, but you can construct a file URL argument like this: `new URL("file:///D:/Projects/Deno/CEF/libcef.dll")`.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75994895/native-deno-v1-32-3-ffi-dlopen-method-error-module-not-found#comment134035269_75994895) If that answers your question, I can write it up as one — if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jsejcksn : I replaced the string with new URL("file:///D:/Projects/Deno/CEF/libcef.dll") and the error remains. Thank you anyway.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75994895/native-deno-v1-32-3-ffi-dlopen-method-error-module-not-found#comment134035790_75994895) @Morph Please update the question with a [mre], including the contents of all required files or publicly-accessible links to such files.

Comment: @jsejcksn I added the isolated code that produces exactly the same error. There isn't ANY external link or lib or what. Just that code in main.ts produces the error.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75994895/native-deno-v1-32-3-ffi-dlopen-method-error-module-not-found#comment134071681_75994895) @Morph Reproducing the example requires the file at `"D:/Projects/Deno/CEF/libcef.dll"` on your computer, but you haven't provided its contents or a publicly accessible link to it. (Is it perhaps in the `Release` directory of the standard distribution download at [this link](https://cef-builds.spotifycdn.com/index.html)?) Please take a few moments to read the full article for [mre], and then update the question accordingly.

Comment: @jsejckn, Yes that is the file. I move the .dll to "D:/Projects/Deno/CEF/libcef.dll" indeed. Sorry for the late reply, I have been away this week.